# Proving $r^i s = sr^{-i}$ in $D_{2n}$

Tags: group-theory, symmetry, dihedral-groups

Let $D_{2n}$ be the group of symmetries of the regular $n$-gon. Define $r$ to be a counterclockwise rotation through $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ radians and $s$ a reflection in a fixed line of symmetry. I am trying to prove a result from Dummit and Foote's algebra book, namely that $r^i s = sr^{-i}$ for all $0 \leq i \leq n$. I'm having two main difficulties, but here is the attempt I wrote down:

> We induct on $n$. If $i = 0$, the statement reduces to $s = s$. Assume the statement inductively for some $i \geq 0$. Then we have
> \begin{align*}  
> r^{i+1} s & = r\left(r^i s\right) \\
> & = r\left(sr^{-i} \right) & & \text{induction hypothesis} \\
> & = (rs)r^{-i} \\
> & = \left(sr^{-1}\right) r^{-i} & & \text{$i=1$ case} \\
> & = s\left(r^{-1} r^{-i}\right) \\
> & = sr^{-(i+1)}
> \end{align*}

There are two immediate problems I have with this proof:

(1) The book recommends induction on $i$, but I'm accustomed to proving such a statement for all $i$. I don't know how to prove it for all $0 \leq i \leq n$. I assume there is some kind of modular equivalence built into $D_{2n}$ so it will still hold for higher $i$, but with less convenient names, but how would I, in general, go about proving the statement only for a select $i$? Do I require that the $i$ in my induction hypothesis be strictly less than $n$?

(2) I didn't prove the $i=1$ case, but I assumed it in my induction step. I don't know how to prove that in general. I can prove it in, say, $D_{10}$, but only by drawing the Pentagon and performing the symmetries. Is there a better way to prove this in general without a picture?

Comment: For (1), note that $r^n=e$.

Comment: It would help others to tell us what $r$ and $ s$ are

Comment: Technically, you haven't told us what $r$ and $s$ are, have you?

Comment: I will revise it. Sorry about that.

Comment: It might help to know that $D_{2n}$ has as a presentation $$\langle r,s\mid r^n, s^2, rs=sr^{-1}\rangle.$$ If I recall correctly, presentations are covered before dihedral groups in Dummit and Foote.

Comment: @Shaun: Could you clarify what you mean by a presentation? Is this just a way of describing the elements as a set? This is what I had in mind for it, yes.

Comment: A presentation $\langle X\mid R\rangle$ of a group is the quotient of the free group $F_X$ over the set $X$ by the normal subgroup generated by the elements of $R$, where $R$ is a set of words in $X$, writing $u=v$ for each $uv^{-1}$ in $R$. It is, in some sense, the most general group generated by $X$ subject to the relations in $R$.

Answer (score 1):

In last paragraph of page 24, it mentions that after we label the vertices of a regular $n$-gon from $1$ to $n$ in a clockwise manner,

> Since symmetries are rigid motions one sees that once the position of the ordered pair of vertices $1,2$ has been specified, the action of the symmetry on all remaining vertices is completely determined.

To prove $rs=sr^{-1}$, the authors give the hint that work out separately what each side in this equation does to vertices $1$ and $2.$

The authors define $r$ to be the rotation clockwise about the origin through $2\pi/n$ radian and $s$ to be the reflection about the line of symmetry through vertex $1$ and the origin.

First it is clear that $r(i)=i+1\bmod n$ and $r^{-1}(i)=i-1\bmod n$.

Next you can check that \begin{align*}rs(1)&=r(1)=2,\\ rs(2)&=r(n-1)=1.\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}sr^{-1}(1)&=s(n-1)=2,\\ sr^{-1}(2)&=s(1)=1.\end{align*}

Therefore we conclude that $rs=sr^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why the symmetry is completely specified once we know where $1$ and $2$ go to. I'm also not totally sure why $r(i) \equiv i + 1 \text{ (mod $n$)}$ and $r^[-1} (i) \equiv i - 1 \text{ (mod $(n$)}$. I'm sorry if these were obvious, but would you mind explaining?

Comment: Since symmetries are rigid motions (which are reflections and rotations in this case), the image of $i$ and $i+1$ must be adjacent. Once we know the image of $1$ and $2$, we can deduce the image of $3$ since it is adjacent to image of $2$ and it cannot be image of $1$. And since $r$ is a rotation clockwise about the origin through $2\pi/n$, it follows that $$r(1)=2, r(2)=3,\dots,r(n-1)=n,r(n)=1.$$